# Properly quote args for calling su -c

Tags: shell, su

`su -c` takes a single string argument, that is passed to `$SHELL -c`. This makes running more complex commands a quoting nightmare if done by hand. What I would like: A function to turn `"$@"` into one string, that is parsed by the target shell appropiately. For simplicity lets either assume the target shell is the same as the current shell, or a simple (b)ash.

```
# Naive implementation:
run_su() {
  /bin/sh -c "$*"
  # To emulate su targetuser -c
}
run_su echo "double  spaces"
# Output: double spaces
# NOte the missing double space
```

I know `sudo` will do this the right way. But I don't want to depend on sudo unless we absolutely have to.

```
# This does the right thing
run_sudo() {
    sudo -u targetuser "$@"
}
run_sudo echo "double  spaces"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume bash, it's simple:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(printf "%q " "$@")"
```

For POSIX sh:

```
quote() {
  for arg
  do
    var=$(printf "%sx" "$arg" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/")
    var=${var%x}
    printf "'%s' " "$var"
  done
}
/bin/sh -c "$(quote "$@")"
```